# NSNumberFormatter erasing value when it violates constraints

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield

I just moved to XCode 4 and from the Mac OS 10.5 SDK to the 10.6 SDK. A behavior that changed is that entering invalid text into an NSTextField with an NSNumberFormatter causes the entire field's contents to be erased rather than disallowing the bogus character from being added.

In my example, I have an NSNumberFormatter with a min value of 1, a max value of 10000000, isLenient, and localization on. Enter a value like "123" and it's ok. Type a letter "x" and the entire value is erased.

The erasure occurs when the field's stringValue or intValue is accessed.

The text field and number formatter are defined in a XIB file. I would like invalid input to be prevented or at worst tolerated and ignored, but erasing the whole value is really not OK.

Another strange thing that happens is that when entering a value larger than 10,000 the entire value is erased. The string value in -[controlTextDidChange] is "10,0000" and immediately after being evaluated is changed to an empty string.

UPDATE:
This was suggested on cocoa-dev:

Try this: Subclass NSNumberFormatter, and implement isPartialStringValid:proposedSelectedRange:originalString:originalSelectedRange:errorDescription: (preferred) or isPartialStringValid:newEditingString:errorDescription:. You may have to setPartialStringValidationEnabled: YES.

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem right now and it's really irritating.

Comment: "`NSTextField with NumberFormatter`" allows only numerals. If you try to set character rather than numeral it will display only an empty string.